# Est-ce « que » est strictement nécessaire ?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, conjonctions

Considérez la phrase anglaise :

> It’s no surprise that she didn’t like them.

En anglais, le mot « that » peut être omis et la phrase reste toujours grammaticalement correcte.

Je veux écrire la phrase correspondante :

> Ce n’est une surprise [que] elle ne les aimait pas.

Mais quand je vérifie avec « Google Translate » ou d’autres services, ils ajoutent le mot « que » avant « elle » .

(Je suis environ un B1 CECRL mais ma grammaire est nulle, désolé ! J’ai aussi compris que « Google Translate » n'est pas fiable à 100 %. Je l’utilise pour vérifier que mon français n'est pas trop mauvais.)

---

Consider the sentence:

> It’s no surprise that she didn’t like them.

In English, you can generally omit the word “that” from most sentences, although sometimes (or quite often) it’s left in for clarity.

When I write French, I feel drawn to do the same thing. For example:

> Ce n’est une surprise [que] elle ne les aimait pas.

But when I verify my sentence using Google Translate or other services (which I *do* know are not 100% accurate—I use them to make sure what I write in French isn’t an absolute dumpster fire :-) they usually add the word “que” back in.

Is using “que” strictly necessary in situations where the English translation could omit it?

(I’m about a B1 on the CEFR rankings. My comprehension is pretty good, but my grammar sucks.)

Comment: While *Ce n'est pas une surprise* exists in French, I'd rather translate "it's not surprise...* by ***Ce n'est pas étonnant qu'elle ne les aimait pas*** (formal) or ***c'est pas étonnant qu'elle les aimait pas*** in spoken French.

Comment: @jlliagre It's not surprise n'est pas anglais. Désolée. Mais je suis d'accord  pour la traduction avec étonner. Aussi, Ce n'est pas surprenant qu'elle ne les aimait pas.

Comment: @Lambie Yes of course, I meant *it's no surprise*, a typo. Sorry. I hate the fact comments aren't editable after a while.

Comment: @jlliagre Here's a trick: copy your post, repost it and then delete the one you don't like. Happy New Year to you. Stay warm. :)

Comment: @jlliagre dang it, I’d even considered using étonnant! I guess it’s hard to break Anglicisms.

Comment: Also, seeing the corrections is pretty neat. Thanks @jlliagre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Que* is here a subordinating conjunction; in French, you cannot omit them like in English. In your example, you should write:

> Ce n'est pas une surprise qu'elle ne les aimait pas.

Note that the *pas* is necessary too (or it sounds very literary and old fashioned), and that the *que* becomes *qu'* before a vowel.

Comment: Makes sense! Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 2):

Just putting this here because the formatting won't really fit in a comment, not trying to replace the (good) answer.

For the record, while you *can* sometimes omit the “that” in English, it's slightly context-dependent. Imagine, *par example:*

> Personne «A»: ***She threw them away!***
>   Personne «B»: ***It's no surprise, she didn't like them!***

The sentence without “that” in it can mean something quite different - in this particular case the missing word can be implied to be “because”.

Comment: Right, in my defense it was a generalization for sake of brevity since I asked via the app on my phone. But, you’ve made a good point.

Comment: It really was meant just as a signpost to future readers! not just as a criticism of your question, I promise.

Comment: No worries, that’s what I assumed. Cheers! :-)